# In the New 52, did Barbara Gordon become Oracle?

Tags: dc, batman, the-new-52, batgirl

In *Batgirl #1*, part of DC's New 52, Barbara Gordon was still shot by the Joker, just as she was in the former continuity.  She lost use of her legs for 3 years, then miraculously regained use of them. In the old continuity she was permanently crippled whe  the Joker shot her, and later became Oracle, who fought crime via hacking and guiding the Birds of Prey.  Did she become Oracle temporarily during those 3 years in the new continuity? I'm also curious how long it was in the old continuity between her being shot in *The Killing Joke* and her beginning he career as the Oracle, as that may provide a clue to the answer to my question.

Comment: We might have to wait till Birds of Prey #1 gets published to find out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DC Senior VP of Sales Bob Wayne stated:

> "The Killing Joke still happened and she was Oracle. Now she will go through physical rehabilitation and become a more seasoned and nuanced character because she had these incredible and diverse experiences."

[Wikipedia Barbara Gordon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbara_Gordon)

Answer (score 5):

I think she may have become Oracle for a while.

> Because near the van she used to move into a new apartment in Batgirl #1 had ramp. And at that time she thought-bubbled that her roomie does not know what the wheelchair helped her achieve, which implies she may have done something significant while being chair-bound.